# Single Selection for ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I am trying to implement a `listView` single selection in my app such that once an item in the list is tapped such that pressed item color state is different from the others. I have done all I know but it does not work well. The problem is that even though my implementation updates each item state when pressed, it doesn't reset the others to their initial state.

[image: expected output]

```
class BoxSelection{
  bool isSelected;
  String title;
  String options;
  BoxSelection({this.title, this.isSelected, this.options});
}


class _AddProjectState extends State<AddProject> {
  List<BoxSelection> projectType = new List();
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    projectType
        .add(BoxSelection(title: "Building", isSelected: false, options: "A"));
    projectType
        .add(BoxSelection(title: "Gym House", isSelected: false, options: "B"));
    projectType
        .add(BoxSelection(title: "School", isSelected: false, options: "C"));
  }

  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: projectType.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
       //here am trying to implement single selection for the options in the list but it don't work well
                              for(int i = 0; i < projectType.length; i++) {
                                if (i == index) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    projectType[index].isSelected = true;
                                  });
                                } else {
                                  setState(() {
                                    projectType[index].isSelected = false;
                                  });
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: BoxSelectionButton(
                            isSelected: projectType[index].isSelected,
                            option: projectType[index].options,
                            title: projectType[index].title,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `index` to access `projectType` elements but you should be using `i`

```
if (i == index) {
    setState(() {
    projectType[i].isSelected = true;
    });
} else {
    setState(() {
    projectType[i].isSelected = false;
    });
}
```

In any case I think your code can be improved since it's not as efficient as it could be. You're iterating over the entire list and calling `setState` twice in every iteration, recreating the widget tree a lot of times unnecessarily when it can be done in one shoot.

1. Save your current selection in a class level variable

   ```
   BoxSelection _selectedBox
   ```
2. Simplify your code to act directly over the current selection insted of iterating over the entire list

   ```
    onTap: () =>
      setState(() {
        if (_selectedBox != null) {
            _selectedBox.isSelected = false;
        }
        projectType[index].isSelected = !projectType[index].isSelected;
        _selectedBox = projectType[index];
      });
   ```

Comment: This is very clean code wow. Would have definitely done the for loop lol