# Flutter Single Selection for ListView

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter

I am trying to create a single selection list view for my flutter application. I want it to look something like this:

[image: Example Image]

I have tried many different ways of doing it, but none have matched this image exactly. This image is from another reddit question regarding the same issue, however **the code is outdated and I don't know how to fix it**.

Here is the link if anyone wants to look at the other person's code: [Single Selection for ListView Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499593/single-selection-for-listview-flutter).

I really need help with this as I am pretty new to Flutter and don't know how to use it that well. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I am trying to do something similar but haven't figured out how to do it. It would be great if someone were to post a code snippet of a working example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ListTile` with `StatefuWidget` to keep track of selected item from `List` of choices.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Choice> items = const [
    Choice('Option 1', 'A'),
    Choice('Option 2', 'B'),
    Choice('Option 3', 'C'),
  ];

  int? _selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(items[index].label),
                title: Text(items[index].name),
                trailing:
                    _selectedIndex == index ? const Icon(Icons.check) : null,
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_selectedIndex == index) {
                      _selectedIndex = null;
                    } else {
                      _selectedIndex = index;
                    }
                  });
                },
                selected: _selectedIndex == index,
                selectedTileColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            );
          }),
    ));
  }
}

class Choice {
  final String name;
  final String label;

  const Choice(this.name, this.label);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code! It works very well and I was able to finish my screen. I may have questions in the future regarding flutter problems so I will keep you in mind for those issues too if you want. Again thanks!

Comment: Also @Soliev I posted another question about a different issue - so it would be great if you could check that out too. Thanks!